# How to order a group of rows together by created_at?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to group the `isp` together and order the group based on the earliest `created_at` of the first row in each group. The visits table looks like this:

| id | name | isp | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jack | Comcast | 2021-03-13 01:00:00 |
| 2 | Jack | Comcast | 2021-03-13 01:01:00 |
| 3 | Jill | Amazon | 2021-03-13 01:03:00 |
| 4 | Jack | Comcast | 2021-03-13 01:50:00 |
| 5 | Jill | Amazon | 2021-03-13 01:55:00 |
| 6 | Jack | Comcast | 2021-03-14 01:00:00 |

The result I am looking for:

| id | name | isp | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jack | Comcast | 2021-03-13 01:00:00 |
| 2 | Jack | Comcast | 2021-03-13 01:01:00 |
| 4 | Jack | Comcast | 2021-03-13 01:50:00 |
| 6 | Jack | Comcast | 2021-03-14 01:00:00 |
| 3 | Jill | Amazon | 2021-03-13 01:03:00 |
| 5 | Jill | Amazon | 2021-03-13 01:55:00 |

I tried something like

```php
$visits = Visit::orderBy('created_at')
    ->orderBy('isp')
    ->get();
```

but that doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$visits = Visit::raw('select *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY isp ORDER BY created_at ASC)')->get());
```

Comment: I believe Over partition by requires mysql 8.0+. How would you do this for 5.x?

Answer (score -1):

To get descending order add `desc`

```php
$visits = Visit::orderBy('created_at')
    ->orderBy('isp', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Comment: I'm not trying to order the result by descending isp. The result just so happens to look like it is doing that, but it is ordering by the `created_at` first and grouping the isp together. Since the first occurrence is `2021-03-13 01:00:00` by Comcast, all the Comcast are grouped together and comes first, follow by all of Amazon isp.